# Adding slash on url after .php loads page without css and js

Tags: javascript, php, css

As the title says i am having a problem when loading a page like
blabla/index.php with a slash at the end (blabla/index.php/).It loads the page without the css and js making the page look like crashed.And this happens in every page i have like blabla/projects.php/ etc.
Any idea how can i fix this problem? And why is this happening?

The code is :

In head.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ΑPL Lifts</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.css">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset = "UTF-8">
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
```

and in another file :

```
<?php
 include 'includes/head.php';
 include 'includes/navigation.php';
 include 'includes/leftContentColumn.php';
?>

     <div class = "col-md-8 maincontent">
        <h1 class = "main-title">Προφίλ Εταιρίας</h1><hr>
         <div id = "profile">
            <div id = "profileParOne" class = "col-md-11">

              </div>
         </div>
     </div>

<?php 
     include 'includes/rightContentColumn.php';
     include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: How did you call your assets?

Comment: Can you share the code your using that you think is causing the problem?  Its going to be hard for anyone to tell why its happening without some code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I think paths to your css and js are relative. somethings like ../myscript.js . You should rewrite it to use absolute path (relative to root) like /js/myscript.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution by changing the ccs and js paths into:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://localhost/apl/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://localhost/apl/css/main.css">
<script src = "http://localhost/apl/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```